# Get Camera Translation from ARCamera

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch, matrix, augmented-reality, arkit

I am experimenting with Apple's ARKit and have a question regarding camera transformations. Which of the values in the transform matrix represent how far the user has travelled from the point of origin? Calling

```
self.sceneView.session.currentFrame!.camera.transform.columns.0.x
```

does not seem to yield the correct `X` translation.

Additionally, what would be the correct location for `Y` and `Z`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The last column of a 4x4 transform matrix -- `matrix.columns.3` in this case -- is the translation vector. See [this old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465116/understanding-opengl-matrices/2465290#2465290) for some background on 4x4 transform matrices and how they work.

Comment: Your SO answers have been extremely helpful during my ARKit work, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to get `ARCamera`'s translation is the following:

```
func getCameraTransform(for sceneView: ARSCNView) -> MDLTransform {
    guard let transform = sceneView.session.currentFrame?.camera.transform else { return }
    return MDLTransform(matrix: transform)
}

let position = SCNVector3(cameraTransform.translation.x, 
                          cameraTransform.translation.y, 
                          cameraTransform.translation.z)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame)
 {
     // Do something with the new transform
     let currentTransform = frame.camera.transform
     let x = currentTransform.columns.3.x
     let y = currentTransform.columns.3.y
     let z= currentTransform.columns.3.z
 }
```

The last column of vector is translation values. you can get translated values from column 3

Comment: add some explanation referring to this block